# Can't change resolution to 1440p - Configure crtc 1 failed

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I'm trying to set up my external monitor resolution using different ways and nothing helps. Currently I'm using 1920x1080p built-in screen and now I have connected 2560x1440p monitor (model: L27q-10).

By default, the resolution of the external monitor was set to 1920x1200 and it is unable to change it even to full HD in system settings. There is also no 2560x1440 in the list, so I used few guides on the Internet. Here are the logs:

```
[17:09:26] jakub@BMO:[~]: xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1200, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+119 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.10*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1-1 disconnected
HDMI-1-1 connected 1920x1200+0+0 597mm x 336mm
   1920x1200     59.95* 
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1-2 disconnected
[17:09:28] jakub@BMO:[~]: cvt 2560 1440
# 2560x1440 59.96 Hz (CVT 3.69M9) hsync: 89.52 kHz; pclk: 312.25 MHz
Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
[17:09:55] jakub@BMO:[~]: xrandr --newmode 2560x1440_60.00  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
[17:10:35] jakub@BMO:[~]: xrandr --addmode HDMI-1-1 2560x1440_60.00
[17:11:05] jakub@BMO:[~]: xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --mode 2560x1440_60.00
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
[17:13:11] jakub@BMO:[~]: xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --mode 2560x1440_60.00 --verbose
screen 0: 3840x1440 1017x381 mm  95.85dpi
crtc 1: 2560x1440_60.00  59.96 +0+0 "HDMI-1-1"
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
crtc 0: disable
crtc 1: disable
crtc 2: disable
screen 0: revert
crtc 0: revert
crtc 1: revert
crtc 2: revert
```

System shows that it is using Intel drivers and the Nvidia ones are disabled. I have also tried blacklisting nouveau, but without any progress.
Is it possible to change resolution to 2560x1440 some way?